# Ember Data with Spring's @RequestBody and Object Identities

Tags: json, spring, ember.js, spring-boot, ember-data

My back-end is Spring (Boot) and I'm getting pretty far along with it and EmberJS. Hitting a slight snag now because when I create new records from Ember-Data, it posts the object with an identity:

```
{ "thing": {"name": "The Thing"} }
```

The default mapping that Jackson provides doesn't assume an identity so it can't map the JSON to the Entity. I have basically 3 options and I'm wondering if anyone else has been down this road and how they solved the problem.

Option 1 - Create DTO's that wrap my entities with an identity

```
public class Thing {
  private String name;
}

// use this for the @RequestBody
public class ThingDTO {
  private Thing thing;
}
```

Option 2 - Configure Jackson via a custom mapper to deserialize the JSON into my standard objects.

Option 3 - Configure an adapter/serializer for Ember-Data so that it doesn't include the object identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out using @JsonRootName and configuring the mapper to unwrap the root value.

```
@JsonRootName(value = "thing")
public class Thing {

}
```

And then in Application.java:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter =
            new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper);
    return converter;
}
```